# Edit edit /etc/mongo.conf and uncomment "auth=true"

Tags: mongodb, node.js

I am trying to disable the auth, and many places tell em to

```
nano /etc/mongo.conf and uncomment "auth=true"
```

Yet there is no config file there.  I have tried also

```
edit /etc/mongod.conf
```

and there is no auth=true at all.  I want to give localhost free access to connect to mongodb.  Any ideas where it is?

Comment: What O/S are you using, and how are you starting/stopping MongoDB?

Comment: using ubuntu 14.04 and sudo service mongod stop, restart for starting/stopping

Comment: Assuming a recent version of MongoDB installed via the official packages, the path to the config file should actually be `/etc/mongod.conf` (not `/etc/mongo.conf`. What version of MongoDB are you running? Is this a standalone server or part of a replica set? Note that authentication is enabled at the instance level, so disabling for localhost is also disabling auth for remote users. As at MongoDB 3.0, auth is disabled by default so if you haven't enabled it there should be no extra config required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is not there you should just be able to add a new line in the file (/etc/mongod.conf) with auth=true.